# sharepoint 2013 - how to select items from another list in a list?

Tags: list

I have two lists list1 and list2 linked with a field named guide, in the list2 I need to have a component that will show the items in the list1 that are marked with a special field and then select the one we want.

example

```
list1
event 1 happens=true guide=1
event2 happens=false guide=1
event3 happens=true guide=1

list2
guide=1
event1
event3
```

as event1 and event3 occured they will appear in any element of the list2 with guide=1 and I can select or not the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you are building your list-forms, if you do it with InfoPath, you could use this tutorial to achieve what you want.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/add-rules-for-validation-HA101783369.aspx

Basically making a DropDown and define where the Information comes from (the other list) and add a rule to only show those items with your special field.